# Micro projector for smart glasses?

Tags: raspberry-pi, projector, smart-device

I wanted to know if anyone out there knows of any micro-projectors that I could use in a smart glasses project. I'm going to take some glasses, a raspberry pi, some 3D-printed materials, and (hopefully) a micro projector, and make some smart glasses. Sounds simple enough on paper. I need it to be small enough to fit on the inside of my glasses near the hinge, and project onto the glasses, reflecting the light to my eyes. I'd prefer it to be off of amazon. And it'd be great if it had drivers to install on the raspberry pi to project the desktop, though I'd be fine without. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think some smart glasses use reflection from a tiny LCD. Big projectors use also a high-res LCD with powerful uniform backlighting (high power LED/lamp) collimated through some lens set. I've seen some 0.42 inch LCDs in Aliexpress and eBay, so maybe a good approach could be to place it on one side of the glasses. Be sure that you'll need some set of lens in order to visualize the information properly at such a close distance. I would recommend you to study how smart glasses in the market are made, first.

Comment: @Carles I actually found one on amazon. Lucky me. Anyway, I will do some research on the optics. I might even end up putting in my own custom-designed lenses.